# How to determine the visible objects on the screen?

Tags: three.js

I need to find the objects that fully/partly visible on the rendered screen. I know this can be done by coloring each object uniquely, rendering the scene, and detecting the colors that end up on the screen. This is a screen-space operation that would involve fiddling with the frame-buffer. Are there any special functions/helpers within three.js that do this more easily?

Comment: It is not hard in itself to download the frame buffer and count pixels, if your objects are colour coded and you don't use anti-aliasing or other effects. But what are you looking for? Performance? Precision? If you tell us more about what you intend to do, we might be better able to help you.

Comment: Thank you. You're right...all those effects and the lighting have to be such that the assigned object color does not change through the rendering pipeline. Perhaps use ambient colors only and don't use lights at all. I'm looking for precision. Performance is less of a concern.     @Berthur

Comment: One thing you can always do is to render the scene in a separate, simple rendering mode, do the pixel count, then render the scene again with the shading, AA and effects that you like. Not if you are planning to do that every frame in a real-time application though :)

Comment: No, it's not a real-time application at all. It is more of a "batch" type operation. What you suggested is just what I want to do. Are there any sample three.js code snippets on how to access the frame buffer, how to choose the back buffer for rendering, etc?  All this and more were easily accomplished in the days of OpenGL programming :) @Berthur

Comment: Sure, I happen to have done something similar recently, so I posted an answer with an example :) Naturally this is not the only way, and I don't know if it's the best way for your application, but I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if object is in view frustum of the camera. See [Frustum](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Frustum) in Three.js documentation.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to render your scene once with constant shading, colour-coding your objects as you need, with any anti-aliasing and other effects turned off, so that you can easily map a read pixel back to its object by its colour.

Then, you can read pixels from your render target, for which you can use three.js' `WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels()` (see [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.readRenderTargetPixels)). You can then read the colours out of the buffer you pass to it.

Something like this:

```
// Render your scene first, into a renderTarget. Then:

const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
this.renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(renderTarget, 0, 0, width, height, buffer);

for (let i=0; i<buffer.length/4; ++i) {
    const r = buffer[i*4    ];
    const g = buffer[i*4 + 1];
    const b = buffer[i*4 + 2];
    const rgb = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
    // Do your mapping
}
```

This is very much just WebGL though, and don't know whether there might be a better way to do this within three.js.